# Sell covered call on an index option

Tags: call-options, market-indexes, covered-call

When I trade an index option (SPX), there is no actual trading going on in the underlying (as opposed to SPY).

But some option strategies (like covered call) by definition require a position in the underlying.

So how does one sell a covered call on SPX ?

Comment: There are mutual funds that track the S&P 100, but apparently not many of them: http://etfdb.com/index/sp-100-index/ http://etfdb.com/etf/OEF/ -- as to whether your broker would consider this "covering" a short call, you'd have to ask.

Answer (score 5):

You can buy some S&P futures or go one step further and buy the underlying stocks that compose the index (which is what future/cash arbitrageurs do). But unless you are interested in a very specific arbitrage, buying SPY and selling calls on SPY would by and large achieve the same outcome.